# How to add vectors/arrows to a PCoA?

Tags: r, plot, pca, vegan

I'm trying to run a trait analysis using PCoA. According to Laliberté & Legendre (2010) this is an appropriate tool because it can handle missing values and traits of different scale types.

First I created a species x trait matrix. Then I calculated a distance matrix respecting different weights for the traits, as one trait was split into three. As the distance matrix contained negativ eigenvalues I used 'lingoes' correction to calculate PCoA. Now I want to plot the PCoA.

1. Species should be displayed as points with **point size respecting to relative species abundance** (see Laliberté & Legendre 2010).
2. Additionally I want to **add the traits as vectors** (see Borcard, Gillet & Legendre 2011, page 143).

So far I managed to do either of both. (PCoA was claculated with different functions leading to the same results).

```
library(FD)

# species-traits data frame
df <- data.frame(row.names= c( "Sp1",    "Sp2",  "Sp3",  "Sp4",    "Sp5",   "Sp6",  "Sp7",  "Sp8",  "Sp9",   "Sp10"),
                 "Height" = c(  10.5,       NA,   36.8, 1504.7,    120.4,    85.9,   26.1,     NA,   39.2,    142.8),
                 "Seed"   = c(   456,      852,    302,     10,      400,    1190,    758,     56,    487,       NA),
                 "Anemo"  = c(     1,        0,      1,      0,        1,       1,      1,      0,      0,        1),
                 "Zoo"    = c(     0,        0,      0,      1,        1,       0,      0,      1,      0,        1),
                 "Ballo"  = c(     0,        1,      0,      0,        0,       0,      1,      0,      1,        0),
                 "Indicat"= c(     5,        4,      5,      6,        2,       3,      5,      6,      4,        5))

# species abundance
abun <- c(0.005, 0.005, 0.05, 0.43, 0.05, 0.095, 0.005, 0.05, 0.01, 0.3)

# weights
w <- c(1, 1, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1)

# distance matrix
dist <- gowdis(df, w) # FD package
is.euclid(dist) # distance matrix is not euclidean - negative Eigenvalues!

# PCoA
pcoa1 <- wcmdscale(d = dist, eig = TRUE, add = "lingoes") # vegan package
plot(pcoa1)
plot(pcoa1, type = "points", cex = log10(abun*1000))

pcoa2 <- pcoa(dist, correction = "lingoes") # ape package
biplot.pcoa(pcoa2, df, dir.axis1 = -1)
```

My problems are:

- When I'm using the `plot()` function I can not add the trait vectors neither can I change any simple graphic parameters like `pch` or `col`.
- When I'm using `biplot.pcoa`traits that conatain `NAs` are not displayed as vectors neither can I illustrate relative abundance with point size.
- PCoA works also with non-numeric traits. However, in such a case no vector is displayed with `biplot.pcoa`,

e.g.:

```
# species-traits data frame
df <- data.frame(row.names= c( "Sp1",    "Sp2",  "Sp3",  "Sp4",    "Sp5",   "Sp6",  "Sp7",  "Sp8",  "Sp9",   "Sp10"),
                 "Height" = c(  10.5,       NA,   36.8, 1504.7,    120.4,    85.9,   26.1,     NA,   39.2,    142.8),
                 "Seed"   = c(   456,      852,    302,     10,      400,    1190,    758,     56,    487,       NA),
                 "Anemo"  = c(     1,        0,      1,      0,        1,       1,      1,      0,      0,        1),
                 "Zoo"    = c(     0,        0,      0,      1,        1,       0,      0,      1,      0,        1),
                 "Ballo"  = c(     0,        1,      0,      0,        0,       0,      1,      0,      1,        0),
                 "Indicat"= c(     5,        4,      5,      6,        2,       3,      5,      6,      4,        5),
                 "Polli"  = c("wind", "insect",     NA, "wind", "insect","insect", "wind", "wind", "wind", "insect"))

# weights
w <- c(1, 1, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1, 1)

dist <- gowdis(df, w)

pcoa2 <- pcoa(dist, correction = "lingoes")
biplot.pcoa(pcoa2, dir.axis1 = -1)
biplot.pcoa(pcoa2, df, dir.axis1 = -1)
Error: is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x) is not TRUE
```

---

Borcard, Gillet & Legendre 2011 *Numerical Ecology with R*

Laliberté & Legendre 2010 *A distance-based framework for measuring functional diversity from multiple traits*

Comment: Are all your variables really continuous numeric variables? Some *sound* classes , like `Anemo`, `Indicat`  etc. If so, they should be defined as factors. Further, in **vegan** you can add numeric variables as vectors onto ordination plot with `envfit` . If you have factors in your data, you can change them to continuous numeric variables (contrasts) with `model.matrix(~ ., df)[,-1]`. This will show classes as vectors of used contrasts, and you can use this both in **ape** and in **vegan**. The `envfit`  function in **vegan** can also add factors, but they are not vectors but class centroids.

Comment: You are right, originally only `Height` and `Seed` were numeric variables.  `Anemo`, `Zoo` and `Ballo` were one nominal trait, but as some species contained  two values for this single trait I split it into three logical dummy variables (e.g. `Sp5` has value `Anemo` and `Zoo` for the same trait). In such a case it is really not meaningful to plot these traits as vectors. Thanks for this hint. `Indicat` is an ordinal variable, therefore I think it's fine to plot it as a vector.

Comment: However, when I first assign 
`df$Anemo <- as.factor(df$Anemo)`
`df$Zoo <- as.factor(df$Zoo)`
`df$Ballo <- as.factor(df$Ballo)`
then I'm not able anymore to calculate the distance matrix with `gowdis`. I can avoid this by first calculating the distance matrix and then setting these variables as factors.
However, when I use `plot(envfit(pcoa1, df, na.rm = T, add = T))` I got two centroids for each factor (e.g. Zoo0 andZoo1).

Comment: Additionally, `envfit` description says `na.rm = T` removes complete rows of the dataset (in my case 3 of 10). I'm afraid that this changes my results, especially when I compare it to `biplot.pcoa`, the `Indicat` vector clearly has another direction.
(Same problem when I use `model.matrix(~ ., df)[,-1]` complete rows containing `NAs` are removed).

Comment: Missing data in `model.matrix` is indeed tricky. It can be avoided with this trick: `model.matrix(~ ., model.frame(df, na.action = na.pass))`. I cannot find any documentation for this in **R**, but when I tried, it worked. Removing rows with missing data in `envfit` is related to permutation tests. I see if that could be avoided when there are no permutation tests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see your point. With `df <- model.matrix(~ ., model.frame(df, na.action = na.pass))[,-1]` I can turn my data frame into a numeric matrix, but it still doesn't seem to solve my problem. When I want to plot the PCoA and the traits with `plot(pcoa1)` and `plot(envfit(pcoa1, df, na.rm = T, add = T))` I get an Error saying `Error in UseMethod("droplevels"):  no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "c('matrix','double', 'numeric')"`